# PL/SQL: NO DATA FOUND while updating another table based on conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

So I have a column on my PAYMENT table that is called Status.. It has a foreign key of another table called reservation with Reservation_ID. The Reservation Table also has a status column and it will only get updated when there is a value in the status column of payment table. So If my status field in payment table has the value "Confirmed", the value for that particular Reservation_ID is supposed to turn to 1.. Otherwise 22. This is how I made the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stats BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON PAYMENT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_STATUS VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT Status INTO V_STATUS FROM PAYMENT INNER JOIN RESERVATION ON PAYMENT.Reservation_ID=RESERVATION.Reservation_ID WHERE PAYMENT.Reservation_ID=:NEW.Reservation_ID; 
IF INSERTING AND V_STATUS='CONFIRMED' THEN
UPDATE RESERVATION SET status=1 WHERE Reservation_ID=:new.Reservation_ID;
ELSIF UPDATING AND V_STATUS='CONFIRMED'  THEN
UPDATE RESERVATION SET status=1 WHERE Reservation_ID=:new.Reservation_ID;
ELSE
UPDATE RESERVATION SET status=22 WHERE Reservation_ID=:new.Reservation_ID;
END IF;
END;
```

So the trigger basically gets compiled but when I try inserting values inside Payment Table, I get the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "ME.STATS", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ME.STATS'
```

create statments for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RESERVATION(RESERVATION_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, MEMBER_ID NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT RE_MEM_fk REFERENCES MEMBER(MEMBER_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL,status NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT RES_status_fk REFERENCES STATUS(RESERVATION_status_id) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_BOOK PRIMARY KEY(RESERVATION_id)); 
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(Payment_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL ,RESERVATION_id NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT Pay_RES_fk REFERENCES RESERVATION(RESERVATION_id) ON DELETE SET NULL, TicketPrice NUMBER(10), ExtraFaciliFees Number(10),TOTAL_AMOUNT Number(10), PromotionalCode VARCHAR2(10), CONSTRAINT PK_PAY PRIMARY KEY(Payment_ID));
```

Comment: `ELSIF` <= this compile ? or is it a typo ?

Comment: BTW, please provide the create table to reproduce your case please  ( [mcve] )

Comment: @Blag for reservation table: CREATE TABLE RESERVATION(RESERVATION_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, MEMBER_ID NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT RE_MEM_fk REFERENCES MEMBER(MEMBER_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL,status NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT RES_status_fk REFERENCES STATUS(RESERVATION_status_id) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_BOOK PRIMARY KEY(RESERVATION_id));

Comment: [edit] your question to add more information ;)

Comment: For payment, CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(Payment_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL ,RESERVATION_id NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT Pay_RES_fk REFERENCES RESERVATION(RESERVATION_id) ON DELETE SET NULL, TicketPrice NUMBER(10), ExtraFaciliFees Number(10),TOTAL_AMOUNT Number(10), PromotionalCode VARCHAR2(10),  CONSTRAINT PK_PAY PRIMARY KEY(Payment_ID));

Comment: @Blag ok sure one sec

Comment: @Blag done editing on question :)

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
CREATE TABLE RESERVATION(
    Status NUMBER(10));

SELECT Status INTO V_STATUS

IF INSERTING AND V_STATUS='CONFIRMED'
```

Could you explain me how you expect a NUMBER to match a string ?

---

Next (from http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01403_no_data_found.htm )

> SELECT INTO clauses are standard SQL queries which pull a row or set
>   of columns from a database, and put the retrieved data into variables
>   which have been predefined.
>
> If the SELECT INTO statement doesn't return at least on e row,
>   ORA-01403 is thrown.

So this :

```
SELECT
    Status INTO V_STATUS
FROM PAYMENT p
INNER JOIN RESERVATION r
    ON p.Reservation_ID = r.Reservation_ID
WHERE p.Reservation_ID = :NEW.Reservation_ID;
```

Is likely to output no row at all...

Comment: I used status in two different tables.. Reservation and Payment.. The one in payment is supposed to be string.. So v_status is supposed to take status of table payment, and then if v_status, which is of the payment table, has the value "Confirmed", the status field in the Reservation table, will update to  a number value of 1.. otherwise 22

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Blag, below statement is giving the `no data found exception`. 
In general if you want to know the exact line number the error is pointing to you can refer to the object via `DBA_SOURCE` or `ALL_SOURCES`.

```
SELECT
    Status INTO V_STATUS
FROM PAYMENT p
INNER JOIN RESERVATION r
    ON p.Reservation_ID = r.Reservation_ID
WHERE p.Reservation_ID = :NEW.Reservation_ID;
```